# SQL Display custom records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two dates, example 01-Feb-2018 and 02-Feb-2018

I want to display some new users added in hour basis, like,

```
            Date                  Total
    ---------------------------------------------
    01-Feb-2018 12:00:00 AM |      25
    01-Feb-2018 01:00:00 AM |      50
   ..................
   .................
   ............
   02-Feb-2018 11:00:00 PM  |      45
```

I want the result like this in SQL.
Appreciate if you suggest an idea.

Comment: Learn to think in sets. You need 2 things. First, you need a set of sequential numbers - web search that to find examples. Given a set of numbers you can add those numbers (via dateadd) to a beginning date to generate a set of dates between beginning date and ending date. That same set of numbers can also be (cross) joined to the first set to add hours to those dates to achieve what you desire. Now - go forth and learn to use sets.

Answer (score 0):

One relatively simple method:

```
select cast(date as date) as dte, datepart(hour, date) as hh, count(*)
from t
group by cast(date as date), datepart(hour, date)
order by dte, hh;
```

This doesn't do *exactly* what you want because it has two separate columns.  You can actually combine them as:

```
select dateadd(hour, datepart(hour, date), cast(date as date)) as yyyymmddhh, count(*)
from t
group by cast(date as date), datepart(hour, date)
order by yyyymmddhh;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired output like followng.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE  ([Date] DateTime, [Name] VARCHAR(100) )
INSERT INTO @MyTable
    SELECT * FROM 
    ( VALUES 
         ('2018-02-07 15:20:27.487','A')
         ,('2018-02-07 15:22:27.487','B')
         ,('2018-02-07 14:22:27.487','C')
        )T ([Date]  , [Name]    )

    SELECT DateWithHour, COUNT(*) AS Total
    FROM
    (
      SELECT convert(char(14),[Date],121)+'00:00' AS DateWithHour,[Name]
      FROM @MyTable
    ) T
    GROUP BY DateWithHour
    ORDER BY DateWithHour
```

Following is the output

```
DateWithHour           Total
-------------------   ----------
2018-02-07 14:00:00     1
2018-02-07 15:00:00     2
```